# PHPSTORM code style - Have different tab settings for view and save

Tags: tabs, coding-style, phpstorm, indentation

I am current required to have all code meet the PSR1/PSR2 coding standards in PHPStorm. This unfortunately means that all my code has 4 space tabs, and I much prefer 2 space tabs.

Is there anyway in PHPStorm to view the code as having 2 space tabs but save the code with 4 space tabs.

Due to our procedure with git I wouldn't be able to physically convert the files between 2 and 4 spaces.

I am hoping there is nice easy hack that could allow this

Comment: there is no way to get files saved and viewed using different styles - every change made to a file in IDE is synchrinized with file system. Also, adding such a virtual formattings may introduce additional problems (like lines mismatching on debugging, wrong positions, etc.) Related ticket: [IDEA-74221](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-74221)

Comment: This would be a great addition. Currently, our standards use 2 spaces, which imho is ridiculous for code readability. I would greatly prefer 4 spaces (8 means scrolling, no thanks!), but to be saved as they expect.